# unable to do : Hive insert into select from different table schema

Tags: hadoop, merge, hive, database-schema

In Hive:
I am trying to do a data merge from different tables with different schema(only difference is additional columns with data can be possible) in HIVE.

```
table A:
id int, name string, v1 string, v2 string

tbale B:
id int, name string, v1 String

table C:
id int, name string, v1 string, v2 string, v3 string, v4 string
```

I need to merge data from all these tables into a new 'table D' with

```
table D:
id int, name string, v1 stirng, v2 string, v3 string, v4 string
```

How can i insert data from source table based on condition from table schema like if column exist then insert that column value, else null.

I have written a query something like in a script to loop through all tables:

```
insert into table D select id, name, v1,v2,v3,v4 from ${hiveconf:TABLE_NAME};
```

This will fail as it cannot find v3, v4 columns not listed in table A

As I have to select from thousands of different tables, I would like to add a condition based column selection dynamically in a script(because there are thousands of tables can have varying number of columns among v1 to v4), as it is not a good practice to write and execute thousands of insert into statements individually.
How can we achieve this in SQL, so I can think of Hive way of doing.

Comment: Stored procedure may help you for this case in SQL, but am not sure about Hive either you can preprocess the data or perform some joins !! https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins#LanguageManualJoins-Examples

Comment: These tables that I am working on are not related, no joins can be made on those tables.

Comment: Any two tables can be joined. Re your question, if you are preprocessing then you know the columns of each "source" table, so select null for the columns it doesn't have before you insert. PS You really are not clear re "merge" & "How do I ...".  Also please read & act on [mcve].